# Why is Gitlab listing the same project folder again?

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab is listing my project group folder twice (see screenshot — link above).

Each of the groups has the same project with the same ID.
I tried to rename one of the groups and the other group got renamed too.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b16F.png]

Comment: Is it gitlab.com or a self-hosted GitLab? If self-hosted, what version are you using?

Comment: It's gitlab.com

Comment: OK so this is using the latest 15.0 version. Maybe this is a bug specific to that version?

Comment: If you remove your search term, does it still do that? (in other words: is the subgroup listed twice even when you do not search for anything?)

Comment: @VonC This is on gitlab.com. How do I get to know the version? Thanks!

Comment: @sytech If I remove the search key then I don't see any duplicates.

Comment: gitlab.com is always at the latest version... which should change to 15.1 later today!

Comment: @VonC — Yep! That's what I thought. Let's hope the glitch gets fixed.